# java - Initialize subclass Builder as type of parent builder with generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, abstract-class, builder

I have Builders within both a parent and subclass. The parent has an abstract builder and a concrete builder that extends the abstract builder. The child has an abstract builder that extends the parent abstract builder and a concrete builder that extends the child abstract builder. The reason for this is so the setters of the parent return the current Builder class. I have methods that return the class's own abstract builder type that I'd like to refer to as the parent abstract type (to call the parent methods on it). All I could get to work was `ParentBuilder<? extends ParentBuilder<?>>`, but that doesn't seem great because of the wildcards. Here is an example that maybe can explain it better.

What I want to do in my main code:

```
ParentBuilder<? extends ParentBuilder<?> builder; // How to do this?
if (something) {
    builder = Child.doSomething();
}
else {
    builder = new Parent.builder();
}

Parent p = builder.setThing1("foo").build();
```

In Parent.java

```
public class Parent {

    private final String thing1;

    protected <B extends ParentBuilder<B>> Parent(final B builder) {
        this.thing1 = builder.thing1;
    }

    public String getThing1() {
        return this.thing1;
    }

    protected abstract static class ParentBuilder<B extends ParentBuilder<B>> {
        protected final Class<B> builderClass;
        protected String thing1;

        protected ParentBuilder(final Class<B> builderClass) {
            this.builderClass = builderClass;
        }

        public B setThing1(final String thing1) {
            this.thing1 = thing1;
            return builderClass.cast(this);
        }

        public abstract Parent build();
    }

    public static class Builder extends ParentBuilder<Builder> {
        public Builder() {
            super(Builder.class);
        }

        @Override
        public Parent build() {
            return new Parent(this);
        }
    }
}
```

In Child.java

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    private final String thing2;

    protected <B extends ChildBuilder<B>> Child(final B builder) {
        super(builder);
        this.thing2 = builder.thing2;
    }

    public String getThing2() {
        return this.thing2;
    }

    public static Builder doThings(/*...*/) {
        //...
        return new Child.Builder();
    }

    protected abstract static class ChildBuilder<B extends ParentBuilder<B>> extends ParentBuilder<B> {
        protected String thing2;

        protected ChildBuilder(final Class<B> builderClass) {
            super(builderClass);
        }

        public B setThing2(final String thing2) {
            this.thing2 = thing2;
            return builderClass.cast(this);
        }
    }

    public static class Builder extends ChildBuilder<Builder> {
        public Builder() {
            super(Builder.class);
        }

        @Override
        public Child build() {
            return new Child(this);
        }
    }
}
```

In the first section I declare the builder as the parent abstract builder type, but I'm not sure the right way to type that object. The wildcards don't seem right. One option I thought of was making an interface above the abstract builders, then I could use that type. But it seems cumbersome to have interface -> abstract class -> concrete class in the parent and each sub class. Does anyone have any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide working code so that we can help you. For example the way you override `build` method does not make sense.

Comment: Added fully fleshed out classes for Parent and Child

Comment: What is the issue of using constructors/factory methods to instantiate those classes?

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code with the setup you have:

```
Parent.ParentBuilder<?> builder; 

if ( something ) {
    builder = new Child.Builder();
}
else {
    builder = new Parent.Builder();
}

Parent p = builder.setThing1("foo").build();
```

Now if you want `builder.build()` to return `Child` without a cast you need to change your existing builder generic type declarations.